# Configuration and Platform settings that make Visual Studio output an IPA file

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, build, visual-studio-2017

I am new to Xamarin and iOS development.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 on a PC connected to a virtual Mac running Xcode 10.1.

I have two apps that I have successfully built, but I can't understand the settings that produce an IPA file.

In the first app, I set the Solution Configuration to Ad-Hoc, and the Solution Platforms to iPhoneSimulator, and the Device i set to my specific iPhone model i have provisioned. This produces an IPA file and i successfully deployed it via the App Center. (I was very excited, only took 20 hours).

In the second app, which is the sample app in BLE.net, if i do the same settings as above, no IPA is generated (the IPA icon is greyed out). When i run it this way, as pictured below, the simulator runs fine (but no IPA).
[image]

If I change the Solution Platform to iPhone, then the device switches from displaying my specific iPhone, to just Device. And if I reselect a specific device, then the Solution Platform switches back to iPhoneSimulator:
[image]

When I build in this mode, I get a pop-up message at the end that says " "Please select a device before running the application". I thought it failed, but in fact it did make an IPA which i deployed successfully (and I could scan for my Bluefruit board successfully---progress!).

Also under iOS Build i checked "Enable device-specific builds" but that doesn't change the behavior. All the Properties (iOS Build, iOS Debug, Build...) are set from their drop-down menus to Ad-hoc and iPhone.

I would like to understand what is happening: when do I select iPhoneSimulator and a device v. iPhone and just Device?

Also, it seems it takes much longer to compile when Device is selected. Am I correct that it is building for many platforms and that is why it takes longer?

Comment: There is a no IPA for the simulator (just an `.app` is produced), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=macos

Comment: Well, I know, but it happened as described above.

Comment: I've given up on Xamarin. I bought a Mac, and it is so easy to get apps loaded onto my iPhone. I'm running Xcode. Yes, there's a learning curve, but it works. I can also plug my phone directly into the Mac and it uploads it immediately, instead of having to go through App Center.